# Use count() with a subquery inside it

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subquery

I have three tables, `events`, `added_events`, and `regs`.

`events` contains a list of events that a person can sign up for. Each `event_id` is unique. There are two types of events, registration types (a.k.a. reg-codes) and classes, differentiated by a `part_no` field (containing 'r' or 'c'). There is an `event_day` column which is `null` for all `part_no = 'r'` events, and for `part_no = 'c'` events contains the day that the class takes place.  That `event_day` column is of type `varchar` not `date` because reasons.

`added_events` contains the events that people have added to their accounts.  Each person will have exactly one `part_no = 'r'` reg-code and zero or more `part_no = 'c'` classes.  Each person has a unique `account_id` which is used to link each entry in the `added_events` table back to their registration info in the `regs` table.

`regs` contains each attendee's name, address, etc.  This table is not germane to this query in particular, I only mention it so you know from where the unique `account_id` field originates.

On to the issue at hand...

It's easy to get a list of all available reg-codes:

```
select e.event_id as reg_code
from events e
where e.part_no = 'c'
```

But I need to get a list of all available reg-codes, and within that query, I need a count of the number of classes each reg-code has signed up for, split up by day.

```
select  e.event_id as reg_code
       ,count(
              select *
              from added_events
              where --everyone who has the current row's reg-code and one or more part_no 'c' events on 04/25/2024
             ) as Num_att_Thu
       ,count(
              select *
              from added_events
              where --everyone who has the current row's reg-code and one or more part_no 'c' events on 04/26/2024
             ) as Num_att_Fri
       ,count(
              select *
              from added_events
              where --everyone who has the current row's reg-code and one or more part_no 'c' events on 04/27/2024
             ) as Num_att_Sat
from events e
where e.part_no = 'r'
group by e.event_id
```

but I have no idea how to make that happen.  It doesn't seem to want let you put a "select blah blah blah" statement inside a count() like that.

If I instead start with the `added_events` table, I can manage a single day's count like this:

```
select   aer.event_id as reg_code
        ,count(aer.event_id) as total_att_thu
from added_events aer
where (aer.part_no = 'r')
  and (aer.account_id in (select aethu.account_id
                          from added_events aethu
                            left join events ethu on ethu.event_id = aethu.event_id
                          where aethu.part_no = 'c'
                            and ethu.event_day = '04/25/2024'
                         )
      )
group by aer.event_id
order by aer.event_id
```

There are two problems with this: 1) It doesn't necessarily get all reg-codes -- if a given reg-code has no class-attendees on a given day, it won't appear on this list; and 2) It's clearly impossible to make this approach work for more than one day.

So...  Anyone got any ideas of how I can manage this?

The idea is for my output to look like this:

```
Reg-code  Num_att_Thu  Num_att_Fri  Num_att_Sat
A         12           27           8
B         18           52           19
C         22           65           21
D         0            12           3

etc., etc...
```

Please let me know if I was unclear on anything and I'll try to make it clearer...  TIA!!

Comment: If a `reg_code` exists in the `events` table (but not on 4.25/26/27), should a row appear for it with all zeroes? Also, what version of SQL Server? (`SELECT @@VERSION;`).

Comment: You can't just throw a query like that inside an aggregate function. I would probably use conditional aggregation to solve this. But your code is so incomplete I can't even really make a guess at what you need here.  Also, when using string literals for dates they should always be in the format YYYYMMDD, no dashes, spaces or slashes. It is the ONLY string that will always be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Note: the OP mentioned that dates are stored as strings ("because reasons") ... so string literals for dates are actually just string literals in this case.

Comment: Just as a note, `count(select * from ... where ...)` is probably something you could just re-write as `(select count(*) from .... where ...)`

Comment: Missed the odd bit about storing dates as the wrong type because "reasons", but maybe those should be evaluated and the right datatype chosen. This however, is way down the rabbit hole and not part of this question.

Comment: just do: `select e.event_id, SUM(case when event_day = 'friday date' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), SUM(case when event_day  = 'saturday date' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),  SUM(case when event_day = 'sunday date' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) from events e left join added_events ae on ae.event_id = e.event_id and ae.event_day IN ('fri date', 'sat date', 'sun date') group by e.event_id`

Comment: Having a hard time understanding why `part_no` is in both `events` and `added_events`. Is there a case where an `event_id` in `events` would have a different `part_no` than the same `event_id` in `added_events`? Does `events` only contain `r` or does it not even have that column? Could you add some sample data (and desired results) here so we can understand the query you need a little better? https://dbfiddle.uk/s6K_iwpj

Comment: Aaron Bertrand: MSSQL version Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU22-GDR) (KB5029378) - 15.0.4326.1 (X64).  And, yes, if a reg-code appears in the events table but not on a specific date, it should show a zero for that date -- or a zero in all three columns if it doesn't appear on any date.

Also, part_no is in both `events` and `added_events` because these tables go way back to the 1990s and it was much harder to do a join-and-link kind of thing back then. Easier to just have the same column in the multiple tables. Same reason event_day is text, not a date. Timezones were a nightmare back then

Comment: topsail had the solution.  Can't believe I didn't see that.  Instead of `count(select * from added_events blah blah blah)` I needed `(select count(*) from added_events blah blah)`. Guess I got myself so bamboozled I didn't even see that.  My bad...  Thanks to everyone who commented.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution -- I pieced it together from comments on the original post.  Thanks to everyone who commented!  My biggest problem was trying to put the subquery **inside** the count() statements.

```
select   e.event_id as reg_code
        ,(select count(*)
          from added_events ae
          where ae.event_id = e.event_id
            and ae.account_id IN (select account_id
                                  from added_events ae
                                    left join events e on e.event_id = ae.event_id
                                  where ae.part_no = 'c'
                                    and e.event_day = '04/25/2024'
                                 )
         ) as num_att_thu
        ,(select count(*)
          from added_events ae
          where ae.event_id = e.event_id
            and ae.account_id IN (select account_id
                                  from added_events ae
                                    left join events e on e.event_id = ae.event_id
                                  where ae.part_no = 'c'
                                    and e.event_day = '04/26/2024'
                                 )
         ) as num_att_fri
        ,(select count(*)
          from added_events ae
          where ae.event_id = e.event_id
            and ae.account_id IN (select account_id
                                  from added_events ae
                                    left join events e on e.event_id = ae.event_id
                                  where ae.part_no = 'c'
                                    and e.event_day = '04/27/2024'
                                 )
         ) as num_att_sat
from events e
where e.part_no = 'r'
group by e.event_id
order by e.event_id
```

If I wanted to get really fancy, I could cast the `event_day` to a `date` type then throw in a `FORMAT()` statement to get the DOTW out of it and compare it to 'Thu' or 'Fri' or 'Sat' instead of hard-coding a date like I did, so it'd work for any show that has a class with a date that occurs on a Thursday or Friday or Saturday...  Which I'll probably do later...  But for now it's working, and that's all I needed.

Thanks again to everyone who commented!